# Apache CXF - JAX-RS Security

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, cxf

Working towards getting a Kerberos authenticated Web Service up and running and while Apache CXF seems to meet my requirements I'm struggling to get things started.

Hosting on Tomcat 7 and my super simple test service works but I can't figure out how to get CXF to provide security:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

    @Path("test")
    public class ItemResource {

        public ItemResource() {
        }


        @GET
        @Produces("application/json")
        public String getJson(@QueryParam("name") int test) {

            return "test";

        }
    }
```

**Web.xml**

```
    <servlet>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
            </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>net.example.test/param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

[The documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-kerberos.html#JAXRSKerberos-Serverconfiguration) says I can protect the Rest service with the org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.security.KerberosAuthenticationFilter but I'm unsure as to how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you asked the CXF user list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use CXF's `KerberosAuthenticationFilter` you have to use CXF as JAX-RS implementation, instead of Jersey.

You can find out how to do that on CXF JAX-RS help pages or in [this tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/rest-web-service-using-cxf). First you have to remove all configuration from `web.xml` because it is valid only for Jersey. Then follow the tutorial to create the service.

Finally you have to add mentioned `KerberosAuthenticationFilter` to CXF spring configuration like in the cited documentation.

**EDIT:**

Because linked tutorial indeed does not run I fixed it. You can download it from my github project [RestWithCXF](https://github.com/destin/SO-answers/tree/master/RestWithCXF).

You might also find useful samples in `samples\jax_rs` of CXF distro.

Comment: Unfortunately that tutorial isn't working, it compiles ok but doesn't run. Happen to know of any others?

Comment: I updated my answer with link to fixed tutorial code. Please take a look. Maybe there are better tutorials (please note that CXF configuration will be the same no matter which application server you use) but I'm too lazy to search it for you :P

Comment: Thanks @Dawid I got it to work using the original broken tutorial but it wasnt fun, your working sample will make it easier for the next person!